# PDO and PHP. Undefined index, but it is defined

Tags: php, pdo

I have a class:

```
class Media {
    private $media;
    private $thumb;
    private $slug;
    private $info;
    private $type;
    private $link;
}
```

And I try to save it to the DB using PHP PDO:

```
$PDO = new PDO("mysql:host=".DBHOST.";dbname=".DB, DBUSER, DBPASS);

$options = array('media' => 'image.jpg',
            'thumb' => 'image_thumb.jpg');
$media = new Media($options);

$media = (array)$media;

$STH = $PDO->prepare('INSERT INTO media (media, thumb, slug, info, type, link) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ? )');

$STH->bindParam(1, $media['Mediamedia']);
$STH->bindParam(2, $media['Mediaslug']);
$STH->bindParam(3, serialize($media['Mediainfo']));  //line 150
$STH->bindParam(4, $media['Mediathumb']);
$STH->bindParam(5, $media['Mediatype']);
$STH->bindParam(6, $media['Medialink']);

$STH->execute();
```

The code above produces 1 error:

> Notice: Undefined index: Mediainfo in C:\wamp32\www\MM\index.php on line 150

But `print_r($media);` outputs:

```
Array
(
    [Mediamedia] => image.jpg
    [Mediathumb] => image_thumb.jpg
    [Mediaslug] => image
    [Mediainfo] => Array
    (
        [title] => image.jpg
        [alt] => image.jpg
        [description] => image.jpg
    )
    [Mediatype] => .jpg
    [Medialink] => 0
)
```

Edit: Fixed second error, quite dumb like @dleiftah said, but one persists.

Comment: Your second error is pretty clear. 5 question marks in your statement and you're binding 6 params. Your bound params are also not in the same order as your fields in the insert ...

Comment: You might also want to specify which line is 150

Comment: The issue is the cast ... as a fun little experiment, right after you do the `print_r` do a `var_dump($media['Mediamedia'])` ... I bet you'll get `NULL` even though the print_r shows data ... I have no idea why yet, but it must have something to do with the private members. I suggest putting a `toArray()` method in your class that will return a readable array ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you cast an object to an array, the private and protected members are mangled. The private members have null bytes `\x00` surrounding the class name. To use them in this fashion, you would need:

```
$STH->bindParam(1, $media["\x00Media\x00media"]);
$STH->bindParam(2, $media["\x00Media\x00slug"]);
$STH->bindParam(3, serialize($media["\x00Media\x00info"]));
$STH->bindParam(4, $media["\x00Media\x00thumb"]);
$STH->bindParam(5, $media["\x00Media\x00type"]);
$STH->bindParam(6, $media["\x00Media\x00link"]);
```

If they were protected members, they would start with `\x00*\x00`

Also, it appears that the order you are binding parameters does not match the order of fields in your insert statement.

Comment: Why would people ever do this to PHP? Is there any greater purpose, or is it just to make a progrmmers life miserable. And why was Mediainfo the only one affected?

Comment: All of them were affected ... your database record would have been all nulls ... I have no idea why the info one was the only one throwing a notice ... it's odd. As for the reasoning, The mangling is done so that if the array is re-cast as an object, php can properly set the members ...